# Attachments missing from an applicant profile while I attached these documents to their profile while filling a form

Tags: contacts, webform-civicrm, activities, civicrm-buildkit, attachments

[image: Can View Attachments is an Activity but the same attachments are missing from an applicant profile] When I filled a web form for an applicant, I attached some documents files too that can be viewed in an activity but when I opened the applicant contact profile their attachments are missing not visible in their contact profiles. Need help to resolve ASAP

Comment: If they're stored in an activity, they won't appear on the contact summary, they'll appear in the activity. That makes sense to me since a person might have several application forms and if they're on the contact summary how would you tell which application it goes with?

Comment: Resolved, those fields in a form were not added in a custom field that's why i was unable to view in contact summary.